# Ionic2 serve not working

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, serve

When i write ionic serve nothing opens. I have tried changing nodejs versions. Reinstalling ionic cordova. Also cleared cache and other ways on internet. Nothing works. Please help. No errors are shown but a window is not opened.

Info:

```
C:\Projects\cutePuppyPics>ionic info

cli packages: (C:\Users\Tullo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.4
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v8.9.1
    npm  : 5.5.1
    OS   : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Serve:

```
C:\Projects\cutePuppyPics>ionic serve
Starting app-scripts server: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser -
Ctrl+C to cancel
[20:52:58]  watch started ...
[20:52:58]  build dev started ...
[20:52:58]  clean started ...
[20:52:58]  clean finished in 12 ms
[20:52:58]  copy started ...
[20:52:58]  deeplinks started ...
[20:52:58]  deeplinks finished in 40 ms
[20:52:58]  transpile started ...
[20:53:03]  transpile finished in 5.17 s
[20:53:03]  preprocess started ...
[20:53:04]  preprocess finished in 4 ms
[20:53:04]  webpack started ...
[20:53:04]  copy finished in 5.44 s
[20:53:13]  webpack finished in 9.14 s
[20:53:13]  sass started ...
[20:53:14]  sass finished in 1.68 s
[20:53:14]  postprocess started ...
[20:53:14]  postprocess finished in 16 ms
[20:53:14]  lint started ...
[20:53:14]  build dev finished in 16.32 s
[20:53:14]  watch ready in 16.47 s`enter code here`
[20:53:14]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/

[OK] Development server running!
     Local: http://localhost:8100
     External: http://192.168.10.8:8100
     DevApp: cutePuppyPics@8100 on LAPTOP-NNU75MUT
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the browser doesn't open automatically. Try entering `http://localhost:8100` on your browser manually after `ionic serve`.

Answer (score 0):

force an ip adresse

> ionic serve --address YOUR_IP_ADDRESS

your ip adresse should be available , i think you can use 192.168.10.8 or 127.0.0.1